# Detecting rectangle adjacency in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, shapes

I have implemented the following `Rectangle` POJO with correct `intersects(Rectangle)` and `contains(Rectangle)` methods:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double x;       // x-value of upper-left corner of rectangle
    private double y;       // y-value of upper-left corner of rectangle
    private double width;   // width of the rectangle
    private double height;  // height of the rectangle

    // Returns true if this Rectangle intersects otherRectangle.
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        double x = otherRectangle.getX();
        double y = otherRectangle.getY();
        double w = otherRectangle.getWidth();
        double h = otherRectangle.getHeight();
        double x0 = getX();
        double y0 = getY();

        if(isEmpty() || w <= 0 || h <= 0)
            return false;

        return (
            x + w > x0 &&
            y + h > y0 &&
            x < x0 + getWidth() &&
            y < y0 + getHeight()
        );
    }

    // Returns true if this Rectangle contains otherRectangle.
    public boolean contains(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        double x = otherRectangle.getX();
        double y = otherRectangle.getY();
        double w = otherRectangle.getWidth();
        double h = otherRectangle.getHeight();
        double x0 = getX();
        double y0 = getY();

        return (
            x >= x0 &&
            y >= y0 &&
            x < x0 + getWidth() &&
            y < y0 + getHeight()
        );
    }

    // Returns true if this Rectangle is adjacent to otherRectangle.
    public boolean isAdjacentTo(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to implement `isAdjacentTo` and am choking. I was told by another SOer that, for adjacency, I could:

> ...just do containment checks on one axis (like the top and bottom sides), and then make sure each corner is NOT contained in the other direction (like horizontally).

But still I'm not visualizing the solution. Any ideas? Optimally I could make use of the `intersects` and `contains` methods, but I'll take anything that truly works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adjacent to? Do you mean they share a side? Are the corners necessarily in the same place? What if the sides overlap, but one is side is not necessarily contained in the other?

Comment: Hi @jgon (+1 for raising some good points). I guess I'm not understanding your questions entirely, so let me ask you a few in return. Once I understand what you're asking, I'll update my question to reflect whatever information is missing...

Comment: 1. Yes, by `isAdjacentTo`, I mean "sharing one side".

Comment: 2. Corners: not sure what you mean by this? Can you give me an example of what you mean when you say "*Are the corners necessarily in the same place?*"?

Comment: 3. "*What if the sides overlap...*"? I think this is the root of my confusion. To me, when two rectangles share the same side, the side they share is the same exact line. Since points are infinitely small, and a line is a collection of points, then a line can't have any width. Sooo.... if they share the same side, **don't they have to overlap?!?** How can two shapes share a side, but that side is two different lines? Otherwise, there would always be a tiny little gap between the two sides, and they wouldn't be shared/adjacent!

Comment: Let's see ok 
1. Great. You're using doubles make sure you use some sort of tolerance thing to check whether they're equal.
2. Never mind, I can tell it's irrelevant now.
3. Well yes, but computers aren't perfect. sooo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I'm going to make up some methods `leftSide()`, `rightSide()`, `topSide()` and `bottomSide()` which are the left, right, top, and bottom of the rectangles respectively (bottom is numerically smaller than top, though if it were displayed on a screen it would be the top).

Then the code:

```
// Returns true if this Rectangle is adjacent to otherRectangle.
public boolean isAdjacentTo(Rectangle otherRectangle, double tolerance) {
    if(Math.abs(getLeftSide()-otherRectangle.getRightSide())<tolerance||Math.abs(otherRectangle.getLeftSide()-getRightSide())<tolerance)
    {
        return !(getTopSide()<otherRectangle.getBottomSide()||otherRectangle.getTopSide()<getBottomSide());
    }
    if(Math.abs(getTopSide()-otherRectangle.getBottomSide())<tolerance||Math.abs(otherRectangle.getTopSide()-getBottomSide())<tolerance)
    {
        return !(getRightSide()<otherRectangle.getLeftSide()||otherRectangle.getRightSide()<getLeftSide());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now here's what it does.
Is the top side of one the same as the bottom side of the other?
Yes -> return true if there is no space between them. (I'm checking to see if the right side of one is to the left of the left side of the other (for both rectangles))
No -> do the same thing for sharing right/left sides

If they don't share right/left sides return false because they don't share any sides.

tolerance is used because you can't compare doubles for equality.